# MongoDB: storing large text data

Tags: database, mongodb, database-schema

I'm currently storing 100-200Kb HTML documents "as is" in bson documents. I have ~300K records.
I don't need to run search in that data, just to retrieve full HTML content by document _id.

I have an imperession that some queries became a bit long. At least, when I run the "Documents count" operation, it takes about 15-20 seconds. At the same time, if I run the same operation on another collection of ~300K lightweight records, it's very fast.

I'm starting to think that I should probably redesign my database schema.
Should I store my HTML documents as files (probably using GridFS)?

Comment: GridFS is just an extension on top of regular mongo storage to overcome 16Mb limit. Storing HTML as local files will definitely help. Did you consider CDN?

Comment: Late to the party, so this probably isn't an issue anymore. Certainly different ways to store the data are reasonable to consider. But why is the count slow? What specific count operation were you running? If you have a supporting index then the size of other (unindexed) fields often won't affect things too much. But scanning (large) documents to count things could absolutely slow things down